# Proof that the unit sphere of any Hilbert space is a $C^k$-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I have come across that proof idea of how to show that the unit sphere $S:=\{x\in H:\|x\|=1\}$ of the Hilbert space $(H,(.,.))$ is a $C^k$-manifold, where $k\in\mathbf{N}$.

For $x_0\in S$ one takes $U_{x_0}:=\{x\in S: (x,x_0)>0\}$ and defines charts via $\phi_{x_0}: U_{x_0}\rightarrow \hat{U}_{x_0}, x\mapsto x-(x,x_0)x_0$ with $\phi_{x_0}(U_{x_0})=\hat{U}_{x_0}:=\{x\in H: x\perp x_0 \land \|x\|<1\}$. I also know $\phi_{x_0}^{-1}: x\mapsto x+\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}x_0$ is the inverse.

$\{U_{x_0}:x_0\in S\}$ covering $S$ is trivial by definition.

With the inverse function I also know that $\phi_{x_0}$ are bijective.

What is left and I cannot show is the following:

(a) $\phi_{x_0}(U_{x_0})$ is open in $H$ and $\phi_{x_0}(U_{x_0}\cap U_{x_1})$ is open in $H$ for any $x_0,x_1\in S$.

(b) For any $x_0,x_1\in S$ the map $\phi_{x_1}\circ \phi_{x_0}^{-1}$ is a $C^k$-diffeomorphism.

If I were to have proven (a) and (b), then that would give me an atlas of class $C^k$ on $S$, which would be enough for $S$ to be a $C^k$-manifold.

Can you help me out with the rest?

Answer (score 0):

I am not terribly familiar with infinite dimensional manifolds, but comparing this with the usual story of $S^{n-1}\subset R^n$, I can provide the following answer.

(a) $\hat U_{x_0}=\phi_{x_0}(U_{x_0})$ is not open in $H$, but open in $x_0^\perp = \{x\in H: x\perp x_0\}$. This is a proper closed subspace in $H$, but it is not open in $H$.

$\hat U_{x_0}\subset x_0^\perp$ is open since it is defined by the equation $\|x\|<1$.

Now for a different $x_1\in S$, you can compute that
$$\phi_{x_0}(U_{x_0}\cap U_{x_1}) = \{x\in \hat U_{x_0}: (\phi_{x_0}^{-1}(x), x_1) = (x + \sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}x_0, x_1)>0\},$$
and this is an open set in $\hat U_{x_0}$ defined as the inverse image of $(0, \infty)$ under a continuous function.

(b) Similiarly, on $\phi_{x_0}(U_{x_0}\cap U_{x_1})$, the map
$$
\phi_{x_1}\circ \phi_{x_0}^{-1}(x) = \phi_{x_1}\big(x + \sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}x_0\big)
= x + \sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}x_0 - \big(x + \sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}x_0, x_1\big) x_1
$$
is a $C^k$ map on $\|x\|<1$. The similarly defined inverse is also $C^k$, so the transition map $\phi_{x_1}\circ \phi_{x_0}^{-1}$ is a $C^k$ diffeomorphism.

Comment: (a) the continous function you mentioned is $x\mapsto (x+\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}x_0,x_1)$ by looking at the set, right? and regarding (b): why is this map of class $C^k$ and its inverse, too?

Comment: For (a), sure. For (b), this map $\phi_{x_1}\circ \phi_{x_0}^{-1}$ is of class $C^r$ (actually $C^\infty$?) since each piece is $C^r$: $x$ is $C^r$, $(1-\|x\|^2)$ is a $C^r$ function, and $\sqrt{1-t}$ is a $C^\infty$ function when $t<1$, so the composition $\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}$ is $C^r$ in $x$, and the last term just has the inner product of this with $x_1$. The inverse $\phi_{x_0}\circ \phi_{x_1}^{-1}$ is defined in the same way with $x_0$ and $x_1$ switched, so also $C^r$.